# Why do browsers go back one page when pressing minus key 4 times?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer

I'm currently debugging some [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and noticed that on any page Firefox plus Internet Explorer 7 and 8 go back to the previous page if you press the minus key 4 times in quick succession. What is the reason?

Comment: I don't get this behaviour on Firefox 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing this behavior in Internet Explorer 8 or Firefox. Do you have any custom hotkeys defined with [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) or JavaScript keyboard shortcuts in your code?

Comment: Rogue AHK script I think!

Comment: They can be nasty if you forget about them :P

Comment: AHK = AutoHotkey, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey